# How to get the Full Path of a File?

Tags: c#

I try to get the Full Path of a File.  ie. `calc`

```
Input:  calc
Expected output:  C:\WINDOWS\system32\calc.exe
```

I could find out how to do it with PowerShell:

```
(Get-Command calc).Source
```

Or with CommandLine:

```
where.exe calc
```

But unfortunately I can not get it done with C#.

Comment: Well, you could run that command-line from C# and get its output using `Process.Start`. There are many posts on SO that cover this topic.

Comment: Do you want to find the full path of the executable that would be run if you ran it from the command line? Or do you want to find the executable anywhere on any of your disc drives?

Comment: @MatthewWatson I would like to find the full path of the executable that would be run from the command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation for Get-Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-command?view=powershell-7) says:

> Get-Command * gets all types of commands, including all of the non-PowerShell files in the Path environment variable ($env:Path), which it lists in the Application command type.

So we will need to get the `Path` environment variable and iterate over the directories it lists, looking for files with extensions that indicate the file is a program, for example "*.com" and "*.exe".

The problem with the Path environment variable is that it can become polluted with non-existent directories, so we will have to check for those.

The case of the filename and extension don't matter, so case-insensitive comparisons need to be made.

```
static void ShowPath(string progName)
{
    var extensions = new List<string> { ".com", ".exe" };
    string envPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Path");
    var dirs = envPath.Split(new char[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    foreach (string d in dirs.Where(f => Directory.Exists(f)))
    {
        foreach (var f in (Directory.EnumerateFiles(d).
            Where(thisFile => extensions.Any(h => Path.GetExtension(thisFile).Equals(h, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)))))
        {
            if (Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f).Equals(progName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(f);
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Not found.");
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ShowPath("calc");

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Output:

> C:\WINDOWS\system32\calc.exe

There is always the possibility that the current user does not have permission to list the files from somewhere in the path, so checks should be added for that. Also, you might want to use `StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase` for the comparison.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the `Path`environment variable, split it with `;` as delimiter and loop over that result. Then, check if the file `path + @"\" + name + ".exe"` exists.

```
var findMe = "calc";
var pathes = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Path").Split(';');
foreach (var path in pathes)
{
     var testMe = $@"{path}\{findMe}.exe";
    if (File.Exists(testMe))
    {
         Console.WriteLine(testMe);
    }
}
```

This outputs :

> C:\WINDOWS\system32\calc.exe

Answer (score 0):

I do not know about any way of doing that *exact* thing from C# either. However the paths are usually well known and can be retreived via the [SpecialFolders Enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder):

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

namespace RunAsAdmin
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            /*Note: Running a batch file (.bat) or similar script file as admin
            Requires starting the interpreter as admin and handing it the file as Parameter 
            See documentation of Interpreting Programm for details */

            //Just getting the Absolute Path for Notepad
            string windir = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Windows);
            string FullPath = Path.Combine(windir, @"system32\notepad.exe");

            //The real work part
            //This is the programm to run
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(FullPath);
            //This tells it should run Elevated
            startInfo.Verb = "runas";
            //And that gives the order
            //From here on it should be 100% identical to the Run Dialog (Windows+R), except for the part with the Elevation
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(startInfo);
        }
    }
}
```

I did not just use System (37) back then, as I wrote it when x32/x86 Systems were still a thing. You would need to check how it resolves nowadays.

Note that most of those paths are duplicated in the PATH System Variable, so you could look it up: https://www.architectryan.com/2018/03/17/add-to-the-path-on-windows-10/

Path Variables in turn go back to the old DOS days. Basically if you gave the Commandline a command/filename it would try the build-in commands, then Executables in the current working Directory (.bat, .com, .exe), and then go look over the path directories to again look for executeables. And only if all that failed, would it complain.

Answer (score 0):

I finally tried to combine all three answers and came up with this:

I post it here in case someone has the same problem.

```
public static string[] GetPathOf(string cmd)
    {
        var list = new List<string>();
        list.AddRange(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("path", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine).Split(';'));
        list.AddRange(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("path", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process).Split(';'));
        list.AddRange(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("path", EnvironmentVariableTarget.User).Split(';'));
        list = list.Distinct().Where(e=>Directory.Exists(e)).SelectMany(e=> new DirectoryInfo(e).GetFiles()).Where(e=>Regex.IsMatch(e.Name,"(?i)^"+cmd+"\\.(?:exe|cmd|com)")).Select(e=>e.FullName).ToList();
        return list.ToArray();
    }
```